# How to add a filter in query to only fetch specific files

Tags: soql, files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am running a SOQL query on contentversion to fetch files that are attached to opportunity. However, I am noticing that it is even pulling the notes attached to the  opportunity as well. Is there a way I can run a filter that does not fetch the notes and only the ones that are under Files? Do I need to create libraries or add some sort of filter in my SOQL query to achieve this?

```
Set<Id> contentDocIds = new Set<Id>();

for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : [SELECT id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId 
FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity 
WHERE ......) and LinkedEntity.Type='Opportunity']) 
{  contentDocIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId); }

List<ContentVersion> cvList = [select id, Checksum, ContentBodyId, 
ContentDocumentId, ContentLocation,...... FROM ContentVersion WHERE 
ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocIds AND IsLatest = 
true];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1:

You can filter by FileType of SNOTE `WHERE FileType != 'SNOTE'`

### Answer 2:

Use the `AttachedConentDocuments` related list on the object. Below is an example of how you might use this inside of a trigger:

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [
    SELECT Id, (
        SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId
        FROM AttachedContentDocuments
    )
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new
];

Map<Id, ContentVersion> documentIdToContentVersion = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>();

for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
    for (AttachedContentDocument acd : opportunities.AttachedContentDocuments) {
        documentIdToContentVersion.put(acd.ContentDocumentId, null);
    }
}


for (ContentVersion cv : [
    SELECT Id, ... 
    FROM ContentVersion 
    WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :documentIdToContentVersion.KeySet()
]) {
    documentIdToContentVersion.put(cv.ContentDocumentId, cv);
}
```

### Extra info

I learned something new while digging around. [Here is the documentation on this object.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AttachedContentDocument.htm)

I found this while digging around trying to figure out how the ContentNote object worked. It bugged me that this ContentNote existed but didn't seem to actually have any association to a content document (the ContentNote key prefix is `069` ContentDocument is `068`)

Its worth noting that there is a similar `AttachedContentNotes` relationship as well if you want to only work with notes. It also has an `AttachedContentNote` object that has a WSDL exactly matching the `ContentDocumentLink` object.

A last note, there's a good chance you don't even need the `ContentVersion` object unless you need to actually access the `VersionData`. Most of the fields are already on the content document. When Querying the `ContentVersion` table, I have noticed that whether or not you a query the `VersionData` field, it is returned in the query. This has caused issues for me in the past with regards to a VF page as it very quickly chewed up the view state size limit.

Comment: Hi,
I actually followed your previous answer and added the criteria ContentDocument.FileType!='SNOTE' while fetching the contentDocumentLink and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Good to know, I'm just digging around and learning something new and trying to share it with anyone who stumbles upon the answer, Ill add another note for that as well so you can accept it.

Comment: oh I see, in your edited answer basically you are fetching the files in a slightly different way rather than fetching the files I did. I actually like the new way you suggested. I will use that from next time but for now, I am gonna live with what I have, since I went too far. Thanks again for the help and sharing your insights.